# Code repeating while inheriting

Tags: java, inheritance, methods

I'm learning Java a bit from a book called "Thinking in Java" and I thought of trying out some inheritance/polymorphism. But I ran into a bit of a code that I don't really like the way it is. Here it goes...

```
class Person{
    private int hp, attack, speed;
    public status() { System.out.println("HP : " + hp + ", ATT : " + attack + ", SPD : " + speed); }
    public punch(){ System.out.println( " punches"); }
    public getPunched(){ hp -= 5; }
    /* plus standard getters/setters to save up your time */
}
class Bob extends Person{
    private String name = "Bob";
    public Bob(){ setHp(100); setAttack(25); setSpeed(15); }
    public punch(){ System.out.println(name); super.punch(); }
    public getPunched(){ System.out.println(name + " gets punched"); super.getPunched(); }
}
class Jake extends Person{
    private String name = "Jake";
    public Jake(){ setHp(120); setAttack(30); setSpeed(10); }
    public punch(){ System.out.println(name); super.punch(); }
    public getPunched(){ System.out.println(name + " gets punched"); super.getPunched(); }
}
```

Now this all works as is (there might be a few spelling errors, my version is a bit longer, so I retyped a shorter one here).

What I wonder is, is there a way I can make the methods punch() and getPunched() from classes Bob and Jake not repeat themselves? More specifically, can I put both of them in a class Person, while keeping the function where a person will still print out its child name ("Bob/Jake punches"), or do I have to put it in a static function elsewhere? If I have to put it in a function, how would it have to look like, since I'm also using the reserved command "super".

I know this code looks very trivial and useless, sorry about that, but it's intended to be, so I can really see what I'm doing while writing the code.

Thanks! :)

**EDIT** : While writing this I realized I can just make a protected String name in the parent class "Person" and via a setter override the variable in each of child constructors, *But* I'm still interested *if* it's possible to address to a child variable, and how would one do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I'm still interested if it's possible to address to a child variable, and how would one do that.

To achieve such a relationship, just make the variable `name` protected in your parent class. Then you can access it in your inherited classes like a private attribute.

Another way would be to be provide a protected (or public) constructor, which takes a `String name`, then set it in your parent class. Then implement `punch()` in `Person`. Dont't forget to call `Person`s constructor via `super()` in your child classes' constructors.

I would prefer way two, because it's cleaner (but that's my personal opinion). This way you wouldn't need a setter method and make the `name` attribute kind of immutable, which is often desirable.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I ment to say that I created a protected String name, not a private one. I already did that. My question is simply is, because when one declares an object (ie. Person bob = new Bob(); ) it basically runs through all the info from a child and then reads through the parent info, is there a way to make the compiler "reverse" it's course, so that I can refer to a child variable/method. (opposite to super, which would address to a parent variable/method)... I hope I explained it well.

Comment: Actually, nevermind, I reread what you said. I'll give you the green tick when the time delay expires. Thank you for a quick response! :)

Comment: So you basically want to call a child's method in the parent class?

Comment: Yeah, but I realize it doesn't make any sense. It was just a moment of an idea when I realized the answer to the original problem and I posted the question too quickly. Again, sorry.

Comment: As you said. I doesn't make sense. As the parent cannot know how many or which are going to be the classes that will inheritf from it. So it can't know the attributes or methods from those classes

Answer (score 3):

I'll tell you why I don't like that code.

Basically, `Bob` and `Jake` shouldn't be classes. They should be instances. They don't represent *classes of people*, they are supposed to be individuals. Of course, you could say that the class `Bob` represents all people in the world whose name is Bob, but that is not a real-world use case or even a very instructive one. Why should all Bobs have the same HP, speed etc.?

Once you realize this, it's clear why the code is repeating - because of this bad design, you are writing something that should be common to all individuals, or at least to some individuals (which would be a subclass of `Person`) again and again for each individual. This defeats the purpose of object-oriented programming, and programming in general.

So, consider the name of the individual. All people have a name. So this should indeed be a field in the `Person` class. And it should have a getter and a setter like all the rest of the things.

The things that make Bob different than Jake should be passed as parameters to the constructor.

And if you want to have behavior that is common to some people but not others, it should probably be defined in a single subclass of `Person`. For example, `PersonWithAnnouncements`:

```
class PersonWithAnnouncements extends Person {

    public PersonWithAnnouncements( String name, int hp, int attack, int speed ) {
        super( name );
        setHp( hp );
        setAttack( attack );
        setSpeed( speed );
    }   
    public getPunched() {
        System.out.println( this.getName() + " gets punched." );
        super.getPunched();
    }

    public punch() {
        System.out.println( this.getName() + " punches." );
        super.punch();
    }
}
```

And then you can create individuals - instances - like this:

```
bob = new PersonWithAnnouncements( "Bob", 100, 25, 15 );
jake = new PersonWithAnnouncements( "Jake", 120, 30, 10 );
```

And this is a better representation of the world - individuals get individual HP, speed and names. Behavior is a matter of classes. If it belongs to an individual who is "a class on his own" - say, a `ChuckNorris` class - then its behavior is not meant be repeated in several classes. And you still have to create an individual in that class.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to insert a class in the class hierarchy between Person and Bob or Jake, such as BobOrJake.

```
abstract public class BobOrJake extends Person
{
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    protected String name;
    public void punch(){ System.out.println(name); super.punch(); }
    public void getPunched(){ System.out.println(name + " gets punched"); super.getPunched(); }

}
```

The child class Bob would not then be required to implement punch() or getPunched() as they are implemented in the class BobOrJake.

Bob becomes very simple (but note the additional setName() to set Bob's name):

```
public class Bob extends BobOrJake {
    public Bob(){ setName("Bob");setHp(100); setAttack(25); setSpeed(15); }
}
```

You don't have to make BobOrJake abstract, as I did, but you might want to leave it abstract if you're never going to instantiate a BobOrJake object.

Comment: You're right, yeah, that works fine as well. But I wanted to keep it simple/without abstract classes. Thank you for a response, though! :)

Comment: You are welcome. "Abstract" does not make it more simple or more complex. It indicates to yourself and other programmers that you are not going to create instances of that kind of object. In the example I gave, BobOrJake should probably be abstract. And Person should probably be abstract as well.

Comment: In the case, that every `Person` is able to `punch`, this would add complexity only, since this could also been implemented by `Person` directly. In other cases though, this may be a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I do not think that `Bob` and `Jake` should be separate classes. There is nothing fundamentally different that they do that merits it. Internally they are identical and `Bob`/`Jake` should simply be instances of the same class `Person`.

For example, if we have 100 people all of whom are identical except for their 'stats', would you want to create 100 individual classes? What if we want to create new people at runtime (whether via user input or reading in information from a file)? You wont be able to.

Instead, the internal stats (name, attack, etc.) should be configurable at least at time of object initialization.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Person
{
    protected String _Name;

    protected int _Health;
    protected int _Attack;
    protected int _Speed;

    public Person(final String name, final int health, final int attack, final int speed)
    {
        _Name   = name;
        _Health = health;
        _Attack = attack;
        _Speed  = speed;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return _Name;
    }

    public void status()
    {
        System.out.println(_Name + ":\nHP : " + _Health + ", ATT : " + _Attack + ", SPD : " + _Speed);
    }

    public void punch(final Person target)
    {
        System.out.println(_Name + " punches " + target.getName() + " for " + _Attack);
        target.getPunched(_Attack);
    }

    public void getPunched(int damage)
    {
        _Health -= damage;
    }
}

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Person bob = new Person("Bob", 100, 25, 15);
        Person joe = new Person("Joe", 120, 30, 10);

        bob.status();
        joe.status();

        bob.punch(joe);
        joe.punch(bob);

        bob.status();
        joe.status();
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
Bob:
HP : 100, ATT : 25, SPD : 15
Joe:
HP : 120, ATT : 30, SPD : 10
Bob punches Joe for 25
Joe punches Bob for 30
Bob:
HP : 70, ATT : 25, SPD : 15
Joe:
HP : 95, ATT : 30, SPD : 10
```

Now, if you introduced new roles (such as `Warrior` or `Archer`) that required unique logic to perform their attacks, then it would be worthwhile to create child classes.

See:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Person
{
    protected String _Name;

    protected int _Health;
    protected int _Attack;
    protected int _Speed;

    public Person(final String name, final int health, final int attack, final int speed)
    {
        _Name   = name;
        _Health = health;
        _Attack = attack;
        _Speed  = speed;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return _Name;
    }

    public void status()
    {
        System.out.println(_Name + ":\nHP : " + _Health + ", ATT : " + _Attack + ", SPD : " + _Speed);
    }

    public void punch(final Person target)
    {
        System.out.println(_Name + " punches " + target.getName() + " for " + _Attack);
        target.getPunched(_Attack);
    }

    public void getPunched(int damage)
    {
        _Health -= damage;
    }
}

class Warrior extends Person
{
    private int _SwordModifier;

    public Warrior(final String name, final int health, final int attack, final int speed)
    {
        super(name, health, attack, speed);
        _SwordModifier = 2;
    }

    @Override
    public void punch(Person target)
    {
        int damage = _Attack * _SwordModifier;

        System.out.println(_Name + " punches " + target.getName() + " with his sword for " + damage);
        target.getPunched(damage);
    }
}

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Person bob = new Person("Bob", 100, 25, 15);
        Person joe = new Warrior("Joe", 120, 30, 10);

        bob.status();
        joe.status();

        bob.punch(joe);
        joe.punch(bob);

        bob.status();
        joe.status();
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
Bob:
HP : 100, ATT : 25, SPD : 15
Joe:
HP : 120, ATT : 30, SPD : 10
Bob punches Joe for 25
Joe punches Bob with his sword for 60
Bob:
HP : 40, ATT : 25, SPD : 15
Joe:
HP : 95, ATT : 30, SPD : 10
```

Answer (score 1):

DISCLAIMER: my personal solution would somehow resemble [ssell's one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28285873/code-repeating-while-inheriting/28286314#28286314): inheritance is not needed in your example.

But, on the other hand, we always start learning from the basis. So, the solutions proposed have to do with inheritance/good practice (instances rather than classes), therefore I want to propose you a different approach: [design patterns](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns). In your case, I think the template pattern can be a good choice.

I.e. (sample, maybe not complete)

```
abstract class Person{
    private int hp, attack, speed;
    public status() { System.out.println("HP : " + hp + ", ATT : " + attack + ", SPD : " + speed); }
    public final punch(){ doPunch(); }
    public final getPunched(){ doGetPunched(); }
    protected abstract void doPunch();
    protected abstract void doGetPunch();
    /* plus standard getters/setters to save up your time */
}

class Bob extends Person{
    private String name = "Bob";
    public Bob(){ setHp(100); setAttack(25); setSpeed(15); }
    protected doPunch(){ System.out.println(name + " punches");}
    protected doGetPunched(){ System.out.println(name + " gets punched"); setHp(getHp()-5); }
}
```

The same would go for `Jake` class.

How does it work? By making the main methods (`punch` and `getPunched`) `final` you can rest assured that whatever skeleton implementation you want to provide in these methods will hold true for every extending class. Then, classes like `Bob` simply plug your intended behaviour. The example is really basics and probably not the best one to show the power of such pattern(s), but you can think of more complex templates (or pluggable behaviour), like `punch` under specific circumstances or `getPunched` with more effects, only one of them controlled by the derived class.